# Explaining how to convert a list of numbers back into words to make up the original array

Tags: python

```
import re
sentence=input('enter sentence')
punctuation=(re.findall(r"[\w'\"]+|[.,!?;:_-]", sentence))
print(punctuation)`enter code here`
positions = [punctuation.index(x) for x in punctuation]
print(positions)
test1=(", ".join(str(i) for i in positions))
words=" ".join(sorted(set(punctuation), key=punctuation.index))
print(words)
with open('1.txt', 'w') as f:#this creates the name of the file called task 2 which will contain my data ad allows the computer to locate the fle and add in the data. The 'w' makes the file writable so i can add in my data, without it displaying an error, using f as a variable.
     f.write(str(words))
with open('2.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(str(test1))
f.close()
openfile=input('what is your file name for the compressed sentence?')
openfile = open(openfile, "r")
print ( openfile.read())
openfile=input('what is your file name for the compressed positions?')
openfile = open(openfile, "r")
print ( openfile.read())
```

#This is for turning positions back into numbers
    openfile = open('1.txt', "r")

```
test=openfile.read()
#print(test)

blankarray=[]

for i in test.split(" "):
    blankarray.append(i)

#print(blankarray)


openfile.close

openfile = open('2.txt', "r")

test=openfile.read()
#print(test)

blankarray2=[]

for i in test.split(","):
    blankarray2.append(int(i))

print(blankarray2)
openfile.close


blankstring=""

for i in range(len(blankarray2)):
    #print(i)
    blankstring=blankstring+blankarray[blankarray2[i]] + " "
print(blankstring)
```

The second part of code converts a list of numbers back into words to make up the array. However i dont really understand how it works. Any help would be useful

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Is there a functional issue with the code or are you just after an explanation as to why it works?

Comment: Yh its the second part of code that i dont understand and need an explanation on.